# Push existing cloned github project to new repository

Tags: github

I have a project cloned from github, and I want to disconnect its relationship with the current repository and push in into a new one (not a new branch but a whole new repo). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote set-url origin <new-repo-url>
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is `fork`. It actually creates new repository and mark it under your name. All the history of the original repository remains as it is.

Read more about forking [here](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/are-git-forks-actually-git-clones) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057194/what-is-the-difference-between-forking-and-cloning-on-github).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change remote url.

```
git config --edit
```

Default editor will be opened with the current repos config. You can see remote URL in it like below

```
url=git@github.com:{user_name}/{old_repo}.git
```

replace this with `git@github.com:{user_name}/{new_repo}.git` (if you are using `vi` editor enter `i` for insert and `:wq` for write and quit the editor)

Finally,

```
git push origin
```

Hope it works !