# Allow anyone to contribute on Github repository without prior authorization

Tags: github, open-source

I have a repository on Github and I want to allow the public to send new branches and put in a pull request. Is this possible without prior authorization?  Can I leave it open for anyone?  I have a few people (using Git Bash) telling me they aren't able to push their new branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Forking and Cloning on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057194/what-is-the-difference-between-forking-and-cloning-on-github)

Comment: how is that a duplicate if i didn't know what forking was

Answer (score 2):

The public have to fork the repository first and then they can push branches to their fork and create pull requests.