# github the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github

I just installed git on my Mac and setup the keys for github.  When I run `ssh -T git@github.com`

I get "Hi __! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

When I try to do git clone however, I get the remote end hung up error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you set up your info? http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/#_set_up_your_info

Comment: Ok, I just set it up - but same deal :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have created the repo, are using the right URL and with the right protocol ( you are trying to use ssh)

Comment: So this is that I'm using: git clone git://github.com/jashkensas/coffee-script-tmbundle CoffeeScriptBundle.tmbundle

Comment: @dave - That user doesn't even exist. Again make sure you are using the right one. The URL you are using is wrong. And you are using the git protocol and the ssh setup doesn't even matter.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,

I am honestly a little lost at which point you are (since someone already pointed the user you are trying doesn't even exists) and what you are trying to do so my answer will go from the beginning just in case.

Since I noticed you are using it on a MAC, you might want to try http://mac.github.com/ which should give you an easier time for begginers.

If you want to really go using your console, this might help (http://gitref.org/creating/).

Perhaps the easiest way was just to go to the project you are interested and click 'Fork' on the web browser, this would get you the project on your remote repository, and would allow a way to contribute back to the project as stated on (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/git-fork-is-git-clone)

If you still want to stick with clone for another reason, make sure you get the right link on the project page at github and run the command.

Hope this helps.