# How to use Git properly when you want to create X projects based on one clean project?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I'm just starting with Git so I have no idea what I'm supposed to do :

I have one clean project, a very basic one with just what is needed for every project (maven dependencies, etc). This project is in a repo I created in GitHub, and now I'm wondering :

If I want to use this clean project as a base for all future development, how am I supposed to proceed ? Do I have to create a new repo manually for every future project and then somehow push my clean project on it ? Can I "duplicate" a repo ? Or am I supposed to work on only one repo and create a new branch for each derived project ? i'm quite lost on "how to use Git properly".

More importantly, how can I achieve this with EGit ? I won't always be able to install something on the computer so I would rather use Git in my eclipse (if possible). But so far I didn't find a way to enter Git commands using EGit (and I guess EGit doesn't have a specific button for what I want to do so... ?).

Thanks a lot ! (and sorry for my english if there are any mistakes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I "duplicate" a repo ?

Yes, it is called a [**fork**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309): you duplicate on GitHub your own template repo, and then clone that duplicate locally.

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/frebro/1834845) for forking your own project (since the "Fork" button is only available to fork project from *other* users).
Use a [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) installation for the commands, before importing your local clone in your Eclipse with Egit.

That allows you to maintain two [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) relationships:

- one called origin referring to your fork (your duplicated template project in which you will develop)
- one called upstream (or "template", or ...), referring to your template project, in order for you to update it you make locally an evolution that should benefit all projects of yours.

[image: fork]

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for, I will try that. Thank you !