# Most efficient way to navigate to my fork from upstream?

Tags: github

This feels like a silly question, but I run into it dozens of times every day.

If I'm looking at the upstream repository, i.e. someone else's repository from which I have created a personal fork, what is the easiest/best/fastest/most efficient way to navigate to my own fork?  This is important if, e.g., I want to create a new pull request.

The best I've come up with is to directly change the URL in the browser bar, but that's neither a one-click nor a low-effort approach:

https://github.com/upstream/repository -> https://github.com/myusername/repository

I wouldn't be terribly surprised if there's a link that I just overlook every time I open the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the easiest/best/fastest/most efficient way to navigate to my own fork?

From the upstream GitHub web page, click on the **Fork** button

[image]

Two options there:

- **You're not a member of any organization:** You'll be directly redirected to your fork. Profit!
- **Your belong to at least one organization:** 
  This will open a popup window which title is *"Where should we fork this repository?"*. This will display your avatar along those of all the organizations you belong to.

As you've already forked the repository, your avatar will be grayed. However, it is still clickable. When you hover over it, a tooltip appears which gently informs you.

[image]

Click on it. Bam! You're redirected to **your** fork on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

<del>There doesn't seem to be a one-click link</del>.
As [nulltoken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335418/nulltoken) reports in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18291744/6309) (upvoted), the fork button is one possibility.
It does actually take me to my fork in one click, without any popup window.

But if you want to create a new pull request, this is done from [your local clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309), through a new branch, which you then push to 'origin' (your fork).

[image: fork]

Then you can request a pull request from your fork.
See more at "[How to do a Github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".