# Forking a repo on Github, and then saving it in another repo's private folder

Tags: git, github

It's for a class project, and we are supposed to fork a project, and then save it in the class folder (which is a private repo). Does this mean there will be "2" repos, the fork will kind of be untouched, and all the changes will happen in the private repo?

I ended up using git clone of the fork into the appropriate folder, but I'm worried this might be kind of redundant and I'll have two folders rather than one of the forked repo?

Comment: There are no folders on github. Care to clarify what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that a ["fork" in the GitHub sense is a clone on the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309).
It is done because you don't have the right to push directly to the original repo (which you don't own).

If your fork is done on the server, then you do end up with 2 new repos, one fork, one class folder.
Once the assignment is completed in the class folder (shared repo for the class to collaborate), you can push to the fork (which you own and have the right to push to), and make a PR (Pull Request) from there.