# What happens when forking multiple times on GitHub?

Tags: github

I have a main repository and forked it. What will happen if I fork it again? Will it create another fork or just replace the previous one.

If I could create multiple forks, how to switch from one to another? Is it just like switching branches?

If I could do multiple fork, then is there any limit on the number of fork?

Comment: maybe you should first start with what you actually mean by forking. It's usually spoken as a github concept - are you speaking in the context of github? Or have you just branched your own repo? Or cloned it in different locations?

Comment: editors - how do you know OP is speaking about github? there are multiple possiblities, as elaborated in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6295785/365237)

Comment: @eis My edit was based on the github tag, which as I see now was added by someone else. So it’s very possible that I’m overinterpreting OP’s question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, GitHub will only let you fork a single time. Once you have created a fork, the button to fork a repository will only link to your personal fork.

Or if you are part of organizations, you will get a target selector, prompting you for whom you want to create the fork; but for every account that already has a fork, you will also just get a link to that fork.

Of course, nothing prevents you from pushing a *copy* to a different/separate remote, but that will not maintain any relationship between the original repository and your “fork”. GitHub’s fork relationship only exists from the “Fork” button and can only ever exist for a single fork per account.