# Forking Private Repos and cloning after being removed from Private Repo in Gihub

Tags: git, github

There seems to be little guidance on what technically happens when you fork a private repository (repo) and whether or not you would have the ability to clone that repo if your access to that private repo has been removed.

For the record, if I fork a private repo can I still clone it after access to it is taken away?

I am leaning towards a strong NO due to what I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/are-git-forks-actually-git-clones). Am I wrong on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your access to the private repository is removed, any forks of that private repository will be deleted as well.

See https://github.com/blog/2034-greater-control-over-forks-of-your-private-repositories :

> July 2, 2015 New Features
>
> Previously, if you removed collaborator permissions from someone
>   contributing to a private repository on your personal account, that
>   person would retain their fork (if they had created one).
>
> Today, we're changing that behavior: **if you remove a collaborator's
>   permissions from one of your private repositories, their fork will be
>   deleted, giving you greater control over access to your private code.**
>   This matches the behavior of organization-owned forks, which hasn't
>   changed.

---

The updated documentation reflects this (https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-collaborator-from-a-personal-repository/#deleting-forks-of-private-repositories):

> Deleting forks of private repositories
>
> While forks of private repositories are deleted when a collaborator is
>   removed, the person will still retain any local clones of your
>   repository.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!