# How to exclude old commits in new pull request?

Tags: git, github

I had contributed to an open-source project on `GitHub`, and `PR` was declined by a maintainer. After a few months, I raised one `PR` to fix some other issue but this new `PR` is included older `commits` also. How can I exclude the old commits?

I also got the below `git` commands from the maintainer:

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git reset upstream/master --hard
```

Can someone explain what exactly each of these commands is doing? is there any alternate way to remove old commits?

Comment: I can't give a full answer here.  If you made one or more commits which fixed the other issue, but those commits are sitting on top of a branch which is somehow out of date, then perhaps the easiest fix here would be to just cherry pick those commits onto a branch/base which is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new pull request from fork without having commits of the previous fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885428/create-new-pull-request-from-fork-without-having-commits-of-the-previous-fork)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+old+commits+pull+request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is based on a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), it means you cannot exclude or ignore part of the history without compromising the integrity of your repository.

However, you may `rebase` your PR branch locally and either:

- Force push you PR branch (only if you know what you are doing)
- Close your PR and create a new one with the rebased history.

To exclude commits from your pull request branch you would perform an interactive rebase locally:

```
git checkout -b feature/failure-analyzer
git rebase -i HEAD~10 # Where 10 is the number of commits you want to rebase
git push --set-upstream origin feature/feature-analyzer
```

Let's review this with your scenario:

1. Fork repository

   You forked the project locally

   ```
   * a (HEAD, master, origin/master)
   ...
   ```
2. Implement your new feature

   During your development flow you made some mistakes and you have noisy commits. Unfortunately you already pushed your changes on your forked repository.

   ```
    * e implementation done (HEAD, master, origin/master)
    * d again oops
    * c oops 
    * b implement feature foo
    * a
   ```
3. Clean your work

   It is time to clean your commit with

   ```
    $ git checkout -b feature/foo
    $ git rebase -i HEAD~5
   ```

   Eventually you get this history:

   ```
    * f implement feature foo (HEAD, feature/foo)
    | * e implementation done (master, origin/master)
    | * d again oops
    | * c oops 
    | * b implement feature foo
    |/
    * a
   ```
4. Do the pull request

   Now you can push your work and create a new pull request:

   ```
     $ git push --set-upstream origin feature/foo
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the 12 commits history is not important, I will do basically like:

1. `git reset HEAD~12`
2. `git stash`
3. `git pull upstream master --rebase` to sync with upstream
4. `git stash pop` to pop up the changes and apply on top of the latest version
5. Fix conflict if any, and get rid of the old commit
6. `git commit -m "some message"`
7. `git push -f origin YOUR_BRANCH`

If you care about the commits history, then maybe do as @Tim Biegeleisen suggested

1. Fetch the latest version from upstream
2. Create a new branch
3. cherry pick the commits you want to include one by one in correct order
4. Send a new PR