# Create copy of project

Tags: git, vue.js, tfs

I have a project created in Vue.js, this project is actually managed by tfs with git.

First of all, I want to change the project name so I do steps:

1. Create a new folder (directory) with my new project name.
2. I copy all the folders and files from my old project to my new directory.
3. I open `package.json` file and replace the name property with my new project name.
4. I opened the project in Visual Code and run in terminal command: `yarn`
5. Once it finishes I run the command: `yarn run serve`

But I got an error :

> Failed to compile with 1 errors
>
> Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>
> Error: No ESLint configuration found.
>       at Config.getLocalConfigHierarchy (/Users/MyUser/projectname/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.j
>   s:268:39)

So I have some questions:

What should I do to solve this error? I'm doing the wrong way?

How can I remove existing git relation of tfs to specify a new one?

Comment: try to remove `node_modules` folder and `yarn` again?

Comment: Sounds like you want to _fork_ the existing git project (aka clone and change the remote `origin` to a new value). If so, see the excellent answers in this post ~ [Are Git forks actually Git clones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/are-git-forks-actually-git-clones)

Comment: Yes I try it and same error. Now I have another additional error Error: No ESLint configuration found. @bcjohn

Comment: But its weird because in my original project I don't have this issue with ESLint, why in this replica I have it? @bcjohn

Comment: When you copied the project, you probably missed the dot-files (eg `.eslintrc.js`). Again, do it properly by cloning the project from source control

Comment: And how can I change tfs repository? I mean remove existing connection with git and create new one @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the issue is that you have missed some files when copying the project, namely any dot-files (eg `.eslintrc.js`).

What you want to do is *fork* the original project. This can be done by cloning it then changing the `origin` remote to point to your new repository.

```sh
git clone <url-or-path-to-original-project> my-new-project
cd my-new-project
git remote set-url origin <url-of-new-repository>
```

Now edit your `package.json` then commit and push the changes.

```sh
git commit -am 'Forked to <new-project-name>'
git push -u origin master
```

See https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url