# pushing changes from clone to main branch in github gitlab clone vs fork vs branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-clone, git-fork

New to GitHub  sorry if this is trivial I did not find it,
How do you push changes from a clone to the main branch?  (I'm cloning a repository from gitlab) I don't see a push-button on the GitHub repository page. 
Also if you use git desktop with your git clone do you need to push to the git clone first from desktop and then push to the repository you cloned from?  Is there a way to have all my git stuff sync across my devices?

Also what exactly is the difference between fork and clone?  I've read some stuff on this but I just don't understand.

Comment: About the difference between fork and clone, I'd recommend to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52647026/8370915) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286796/8370915). And try to avoid asking multiple questions instead of specific one. You can always [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) again. [More than one question per post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post/275909#275909) isn't good idea.

Comment: GitHub or GitLab? Why would there be a button to *push* on the *remote*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  so I can push that instead of the git push command

Comment: @HaoS About you comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475853/how-reduce-size-the-header-in-beamer/478221?noredirect=1#comment1423418_478221 : of course this will only work for themes based on sidebar. If this does not work for you, consider asking a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex and I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clone is essentially a local copy of your code. In this instance the cloned copy is on Github, and your original copy is on Gitlab. There is some 
[Github Help Documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/pushing-commits-to-a-remote-repository) that might help you with your answer. Pushing a commit to your cloned repository requires the use of the "Push" command. An example of the usage of this command would be `git push  <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>`, where `<REMOTENAME>` is your compy on Gitlab and `BRANCHNAME` is your current Github repository. You will most likely need to use the Git desktop app or another CLI to use this command.