# is there a way to fork a repo directly using the command line?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I am trying to figuring out how do I fork a git/github repository using command line.

I tried but it says `'fork' is not a git command.`. Is there any way to fork a repository using commmand line.

```
git: 'fork' is not a git command.
See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is fsck
```

Comment: `fork` is not a command.  To make a new branch, use `git branch`.  To create a new repo,  use `git clone`.  To make a fork, use `git clone` to make a new repo, and then call the new repo a fork.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Fork is a [GitHub operation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo), not a Git one.

You can use the GitHub CLI [`gh fork`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork) command to make a fork.

Example:

```sh
# Create a fork for another repository.
~/Projects$ gh repo fork cli/cli
- Forking cli/cli...
✓ Created fork cli/cli
? Would you like to clone the fork? Yes
Cloning into 'cli'...
✓ Cloned fork
~/Projects$ cd cli
~/Projects/cli$
```

That way, you don't have to clone any repository: the forked repository is created and then cloned for you.

This is different from [creating a branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches) inside your own repository.

---

See also [`gh repo fork -- fork-name=xxx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945136/6309) with gh 2.5.0 (Feb. 2022)

Comment: do we fork any **git** repository using github cli ??? or only github repositories???

Comment: @SajjadAli A [fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309) is not a Git feature, but one provided by the remote Git repositories hosting service. Here, it is for GitHub repositories only, using their `gh` CLI: that fits the "github" tag under this question. For GitLab, you would use their own CLI `glab`, with [`glab repo fork <repo> [flags]`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/repo/fork.md)

Comment: Thank you, did not have the option to fork on the website but command line did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Use [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) command line tool that was
specifically designed to work with Github. Install it or download it and add it to your PATH and then do:

```
alias git=hub
```

You can now do `git fork` to fork the repository you're currently in. hub also comes
with other useful commands, for example you can do `git pull-request`
to send a pull request in the command line (do not confuse it with
[git-request-pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) which is
the built-in Git command)

Comment: Hub is now obsolete, and has been rewritten as gh. See my answer.