# Why do git commits exist on my local clone/directory but not on GitHub?

Tags: macos, git, command-line, github

I have committed and pushed several changes for a project using git on the command line, but when I log in to GitHub, the branches and commits I made are not shown on my account. Why?

I can review all commit history I have made using git on the command line.

### Results of `git remote -v` command

```
origin  https://github.com/felixtan/guessing-game.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/felixtan/guessing-game.git (push)
```

Comment: Have you added github as a remote? From the command line try `git remote -v` and post the results into the question.

Comment: Is it your repository? What did it say when you tried to `git push origin <branchname>` for whatever you called your branch?

Comment: Make sure that if you're using a non-default branch, you mark it as tracking first with `git push ORIGIN_NAME BRANCH_NAME -u`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once committed locally, you still need to push those commits to github:

```
git push
```

(since your remote is named origin, you don't need to specify its name: it pushes by default to 'origin')

This assumes you are the owner or [one of the collaborators](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) of the repo [felixtan/guessing-game](https://github.com/felixtan/guessing-game).

If it is the first time you push your current branch:

```
git push -u origin yourCurrentBranch
```

That establish a tracking relationship between your branch and '`origin/yourBranch`', as detailed in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

Once that first push is done, the subsequent pushes are simple '`git push`'.

---

If you are not the owner/collaborator, you won't have the right to push to that repo.

You need to [make a fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611349/6309) (See [GitHub forking](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)), and in your local cloned repo you are already working on:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://YourLogin@github.com/YourLogin/guessing-game.git
```

That way, you will push to your fork (that you own), and will make [pull requests from there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309) (See [GitHub pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request)).