# Best practice for Pull Requests on GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961644/best-practices-on-github-repos-to-fork-or-create-a-new-branch) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611256/forking-vs-branching-in-github) discussions but still have troubles with understanding the best way of collaborating on GitHub.

Suppose I've forked a repo and develop it independently (the original repo has not been active for a while). So I do have my own `develop` branch, where I do all changes: branching from `feature` it, developing there and then merging back to `develop`. From time to time I want to submit a PR to original repo. But I can't do PR from `feature`, as it will include all history of `develop`. So that's what I do:

- checkout `master` that track original repo
- brahnch from it
- cherry-pick from `feature` and push it to GitHub
- submit a PR

When those PR's are merged to `master` of original repo, I pull from it and then merge `master` to `develop`.

It works rather fine, but it results in multiplying identical commits in my own repo, so I'm not sure if cherry-picking is the best way here?

Branching from `master` would be perhaps better, but often there's a situation when I've done feature-2 that depend on feature-1; and feature-1 is still waiting as PR to be merged, but not in `master` yet.

I would appreciate any suggestions and examples.

Comment: Not really an answer, but that's the way I've been using pull requests as well. If your own repo is ahead of the _upstream_, you'll have to branch of the _upstream_'s master branch to avoid pulling in all of your changes. I also use cherry-picking for moving changes between my fork and the branch for the Pull Request.

Answer (score 7):

In theory it always depends on the project you are working on, and the head of the project.

Generally speaking you only commit to master when it is a release build, or something that can **at least** compile without errors. But some project just throw everything into master.

Truly, in my own projects, and opinion, your pull requests should be placed into the main projects **develop** branch, then when the time comes, everything from develop gets merged into **master**.

Your workflow would *basically* stay the same. Branch from **develop** to create a new **feature-X**, commit to **feature-X**, and then you would submit a pull request on **feature-X**. Once merged into **develop** you would pull that down, and continue working; or just merge it on your personal fork and continue working, git should understand. Once the project lead feels the project is in it's next version, he/she would merge develop into master.

Check out this 5 minute read: [Understanding the GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

Comment: Ryen, thanks for the answer. Perhaps I was not clear enough - master/develop separation is not really an issue - usually I follow gitflow paradigm. What I'm interested in - how to send pull-request for only **feature-X**, given that my **develop** is way ahead of the original repository? I use cherry-picking, but is it the best way?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ryen that it depends on what project.

At my work we've come up with a pretty nice system that we all agreed upon.

1. Start on latest master.
2. Work on your development or feature work
3. `git add -p` (for your changes) or `git add <filename>` for new additions
4. `git checkout -b new-branch-name`
5. `git commit -m "whatever you feel should be said"`
6. `git pull -r origin master`
7. `git push origin new-branch-name`
8. open a pr and wait for 2 approvals
9. merge into master
10. delete new-branch-name

After that we just go back to master and repeat.  If someone requests changes we stash whatever we're working on and `checkout new-branch-name`, make the requested changes, do a `git pull -r origin master` again, then `git push -f origin new-branch-name`, then `checkout master` and `git stash pop`.  Sometimes you do get in a spot where you need the changes you made, in that case we just continue working on that new-branch-name and don't delete it locally, only on github or whatever you use.

I know I kind of broke it down barney style, but I didn't want to miss something.  Feel free to use it.  It also works so well for us because we talk and collaborate a lot.  As far as forked repos and prs, just open a pr whenever you're happy with what you have been working on.  I don't agree wholeheartedly with the whole, branch off master to a dev branch, then branch off of that.  Master should be prod ready at all times and then if you're sticking to those prs you don't need to worry.  Also if you're scared of a big pr feel free to require multiple people to review it, and it doesn't have to just be two.  We only have 6 people so 2 works for us.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comment posted by OP on Ryen Nelsen's answer:

> ... master/develop separation is not really an issue - usually I follow gitflow paradigm. What I'm interested in - how to send pull-request for only feature-X, given that my develop is way ahead of the original repository? I use cherry-picking, but is it the best way?

**I will ask - what do you mean that your `develop` branch is way ahead of the original repository (what I'll call the `master` branch from now on)?  What are all the other things in your `develop` branch?**

It sounds like you are completing significant development in `develop` that is not going into `master` in the short-term. In this situation, create a separate feature branch for each Pull Request/issue/enhancement that you are working on that will be submitted to `master`.

If you are careful, you can minimize the differences between your various feature branches, including the interdependencies discussed in the quote.  For example, say you are maintaining `develop` and trying to submit pull requests to `master` for `fea1` and `fea2`.

- Setup the 2 feature branches **off of master** and Cherry-pick or Rebase **out of develop** to `fea1` and `fea2` until they have the base you need from existing `develop` changes to make your fixes.
- If there are interdependencies, that just means you will cherry-pick some of the same commits to each feature branch, or will end up developing new code that will be merged or rebased between the two feature branches.
- Develop the new fixes for `fea1` and `fea2`, and merge (or rebase/squash) to `develop` as you find appropriate.  Merging in this context, where you are the only one developing in this repo is simple - you'll only be working on one of `develop`, `fea1`, or `fea2` at a time, so merging is truly going to be handling conflicts that you have to solve anyway...

Once prepared for the pull requests, you can leave `fea1` and `fea2` sitting in their own separate branches, and continue working on `develop` separately.  Meanwhile, as the Pull Requests get feedback you can always checkout `fea1` or `fea2` and update them, perhaps requiring a merge from `fea1` to `fea2` or vice versa, and likely also needing to merge the new commit(s) back down to develop so it stays up-to-date.

Once the PRs are accepted, you can clean-up anything you need to on the corresponding private feature branch in your repo, and make sure any final merges to the other branch and `develop` are complete.

You could then delete the feature branch, but personally, I'd tag the last commit so I could come back to it in the future if needed, and then delete the branch reference. That way you can come back to a commit that is likely a lot closer to `master` than `develop` is, though depending how much time has passed, maybe not - at least you'll have a choice. This could happen, for example, if a defect in your PR gets into `master,` and a new issue is opened that you can squash quickly, but would take someone else a lot longer.