# How to make contribution to project on Github

Tags: github

On Github, most of the open source projects already have many existing commits. If I want to make my contribution to such a project, since I don't know which step the current project is, and I don't know what's needed to be done next, how should I start my contribution? Anyone who ever made some contributions, how did you start, I will really appreciate it if you can share some of you experiences.

Comment: I think the answer is generic. In any versioned system, you check-out a version, make changes and check-in later. If there were no other changes to the files you modified, your check-ins will be accepted. If there were changes by others to the files you modified, the system will usually try to auto-merge the changes. If it finds conflicts which it cannot resolve, it will ask you to do a manual merge. If the merge is successful, the check-in will go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GitHub specifically, you

- [fork a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309) you want to contribute to (that allows you to have your own copy on GitHub)
- you [clone that forked repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611349/6309) locally
- you [make a dedicated branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309) for your new commits (your contribution)
- you push it back to your fork (after [rebasing it on top of the latest commits from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309), to make sure your work is applied on top of the most recent evolutions from the original repo)
- you make a [PR (pull request)](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) from that branch.