# adding in remote repo into git fork

Tags: git, github

My Git knowledge wasn't very good but I hoped to get some insights on this step-by-step guide that my senior told me as I am running into some problem

Based on my understanding, I am a bit confused where there is a need to add in the remote repo since the items within and the repo I forked are basically the same.

It is as follows:

- Fork a repo using the branch `test_for_validation` within the project
  called `SITE`
- Clone the repo locally
- Cd to local repo
- git remote add site ssh://git@....git
- git pull site
- git checkout site/feature/test_for_validation
- git checkout develop
- git merge feature/test_for_validation

While I am at `git pull site` step, I am seeing a list of `* [new branch]    xxx` followed with a message:

```
You asked to pull from the remote 'site', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

Am I supposed to do something here?

Additionally, when I did the git clone into my machine, am I suppose to create all the branches, seeing that at the last step it is asking me to merge since currently I only have the `master` branch...

Lastly can I check if it is necessary for me to create a repository called `test_for_validation` as I am not seeing this repo of mine in the projects..

I am using Atlassian by the way

Answer (score 0):

> Based on my understanding, I am a bit confused where there is a need to add in the remote repo since the items within and the repo I forked are basically the same.

You would add an 'upstream' remote in order to:

- *fetch* updates from that [original repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611349/6309)
- [rebase your own work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309) (generally, a dedicated branch where you make your own contribution, in order to prepare a pull request)

[image: fork]

So in your guide: don't pull, just fetch.

Comment: How about the branches then? Will there be a need to create out all of them?

Comment: @yan no: you can create a local branch from `site/xxx` remote tracking branch which was imported by the fetch.

Comment: Since there is a need for it to be tracked, will using this command `git checkout --track site/develop` be okay? Adding on, are there any other commands to check if the state of the created branches are tracked or where do they come from `site/xxx` etc?

Comment: @yan yes, that would be enough to track that branch. To check who tracks what: `git branch -avvv`.