# Forking vs Branching

Tags: git, github

In my organisation there is a private repository on GitHub. There are around 8-10 developer working on the repository at a time.

Currently all the devs have there own forks to work on this repo. But, what would be a more ideal approach here for the devs to work on this repository?

Should all the devs have a fork of the repository and work on there individual forks and raise PR once the code is in a mergeable state or should we have branches as per the features and releases?

It can be assumed that write access can be granted (except on master branch) to all the users without any much concerns.

Any particular downsides / advantages to forking / branching which we are unable to foresee now.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed several times in the past and I think this could be marked as a duplicate question.

[Forking vs Branching in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611256/forking-vs-branching-in-github)